# Availability of PXM Indesign connector for Indesign CC 2017?

Tags: configuration

Does anyone has any idea on when there would be a PXM Indesign connector for Indesign CC 2017 available?

I've noticed after an update that the plugin for 2015 did not work on 2017 and I had to reinstall the Indesign CC 2015 version (next to the updated one) to keep on using the plugin.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The product team is working on the compatibility with Sitecore 8.2 first. That is expected in January.  CC2017 connectors are slated shortly after that, but no firm timeline.  From SC product team.